# Does every token that strtok() creates end with a null byte in C?

Tags: c

When you're using the `strtok()` function in C (not C++), does every token automatically end with a null byte? How exactly would you check?

If I recall correctly, the `strlen()` function does not include the terminating byte when it calculates the length of the string.

Comment: There is no such thing as a string that doesn't end with a null byte - if it doesn't end with a null byte then it's not a string.

Answer (score 3):

From the man page:

Each call to `strtok()` returns a pointer to a nul-terminated string containing the next token.

So the short answer is "Yes". Think about it. If the return was not nul terminated then it wouldn't be tokenizing because you wouldn't just get the token, you'd get the token and the rest of the string as well...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the answer is `yes`. Please note that `strtok` will **modify** the original string. The function will replace token character with `null character`. Take a look at https://ideone.com/u4W2PC