# When does a char* ends with null in c?

Tags: c, string, null-terminated

I have confusion on char* `null-termination` so i have decided to make a study of cases i can find. Do these string literals end with a null?

1. `char str1[512]="This is a random string"`
2. `char *str2 = strtok(buffer,"\n,")` I have found its answer. [This ends with null.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564794/does-every-token-that-strtok-creates-end-with-a-null-byte-in-c)
3. `fgets(stdin, str3, 512)`
4. `scanf("%s",str4)`
5. The code snippet:

   ```
   char str[5];    
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++) scanf("%c",&str[i]);
   ```

**Note** 1: I have an assumption that all standard functions in c library that returns a `char*`, null terminates the string.
**Note 2:** How do I check if a string is null terminated or not? (I tried [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/76X7dbMP7V/) approach but it prints random stuffs imo.)

**Edit**: *Just showing me a way to determine whether a string literal is null-terminated will be enough. I will go through each case and update here for future readers.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are C strings always null terminated, or does it depend on the platform?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/344603/30872)

Comment: *When does a string ends with null in c?*  **Always**.  It's not a "string" in C if it doesn't end with a `'\0'` character

Comment: @GSerg, thanks! I went through it and it does not answer my question, though it did clear some of my doubts. And @Andrew, thanks, i will edit my question to `char*`

Comment: The only way for a string to not be null-terminated is if the programmer erroneously failed to terminate it. This is indistinguishable from properly terminated strings because you are bound to reach a null sooner or later (though in the "later" case you might trip on an access violation error before that happens). There really is no way to answer "no", but also no good way for the compiler to know when you did this on purpose (to glue together two strings, or manipulate fixed-width structures which don't require termination for external reasons) and when it is a mistake.

Comment: You missed a case that should be understood: `char t[3] = "abcdefghi"`

Comment: In cases of character-by-character input, the programmer is required to set '\0 ' independently. But let's say the scanf ( ) function, if the %s specifier is used, sets '\0 ' automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an example is by no means exhaustive, but it brings some clarity. The answer is actually simple. Any array of characters ending in '\0' is called a string. The programmer independently decides what he needs .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char w[]="mamamia";
int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(w);i++)
{
if(w[i]=='\0')
    printf("w[%d]==null\n",i);
else
    printf("w[%d]== %c \n",i,w[i]);
}
    return 0;
}
```